# Using Less with .net web development

Tags: visual-studio, less

So I am very interested in using LESS with Bootstrap and Visual Studio.  THe problem I'm having is that Web Essentials doesn't seem to be able to compile css from the Bootstrap LESS files.  I've done some poking around and it seems that Web Essentials doesn't understand semicolons or something to that effect, which is causing it to choke on bootstrap's less files.

So, are people using LESS with bootstrap in a VS environment, or have I wandered onto the fringe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tools you could use:

- [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) - I can tell you it does work with Bootstrap as I've used it before
- [Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) - A paid alternative, I prefer web essentials
- [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com) - A JavaScript task runner that you can configure to build various resources and hook it up to your post-compile step so it happens automatically

Personally I'd go with grunt, while it's not very commonly used tool in '.NET', once you've used it you can see the awesome power it gives you. It's open source, and has a tonne of open source plugins that lets you do heaps of stuff, plus you can write your own.

Some examples of plugins: minify JavaScript; compile SASS, LESS, TypeScript, CoffeeScript, Markdown, etc.; copy files; delete files; optimize images and so on.

Comment: Thanks -- i didn't think that WebEssentials was working, because it was giving me inline errors (squiggles) on some of the bootstrap less declarations, but despite that, I found that it was compiling the css correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out WebEssentials (as you've already found, [if it doesn't work, try filing a request](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general) or [an issue](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2012/issues)) or the [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) and finally the [BundleTransformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/). Your request isn't a fringe, the web is embracing these technologies, so is Visual Studio.

If you'd share the exact messages you're seeing, or the steps you've taken so that we can reproduce, we can help you better. As far as I can tell WebEssentials should work with Bootstrap's less files just fine.